# Angular - How to insert dynamic SVG into DOM via component

Tags: angular

I am trying to insert SVG elements into the DOM using an angular component, and having problems.  My app is to display a toolbox of Icons that I can drag onto a workspace.  the Icons are SVG based.  I do not want to create a component for each Icon.  I would add the Icon to the parent Component array and the HTML below shows my loop using the app-edge-component to insert the SVG. 
Below is example HTML of parent component.

**flow-chart.component.html**

```
<svg id="top_svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g app-edge-component [node]="node" [nodeIndex]="nodeIndex" *ngFor="let node of chart.nodes; let nodeIndex = index" [id]="'NodeGroup-' + nodeIndex">
    </g>
</svg>
```

Below is my app-edge-component code

**edge-component.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NodeViewModel } from '../flow-chart/flow-chart.nodeviewmodel';
import { SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser/src/security/dom_sanitization_service';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
    // tslint:disable-next-line:component-selector
    selector: 'g[app-edge-component]',
    templateUrl: 'edge-component.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['edge-component.component.scss']
})

export class EdgeComponentComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() node
        : NodeViewModel;

    @Input() nodeIndex
    : number;

    @ViewChild('dataContainer') dataContainer: ElementRef;

    svgTemplate: SafeHtml;

    mouseOverNode = null;

    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        // Try using container
        // this.dataContainer.nativeElement.html = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml('<svg:circle cx="0" cy="0" r="10"/>');

        // Try using innerHTML on div
        this.svgTemplate = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml('<svg:circle cx="0" cy="0" r="10"/>');
    }

    onNodeMouseDown(e, nodeIndex) {
    }
}
```

**edge-component.component.html**

```
<!-- <ng-container #dataContainer></ng-container> -->
<div [innerHTML]="svgTemplate" #dataContainer></div>
```

As can be seen above I have had many attempts to insert the SVG and the **div** with [innerHTML] comes the closest, and the DOM shows the **svg:circle** inside a **div** but it does not render on the browser.  I am not sure a div is allowed inside svg elements and that is why.

Comment: Have you tried to use a valid SVG element in the template (instead of *div*), e.g. `g`?

Comment: I did try with a <g> but the compiler errors because innerHTML is not a member of <g>

Comment: Did you try to use <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="10"/>? without svg